# API is not giving any response

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to call an API for some registration form but it does not give any response neither an error or a success message I cannot find what's wrong with my code.

```
navigationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (BusinessType.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Business Type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (AdhaarNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Adhaar Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (PAN.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the PAN Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (GSTIN.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the GSTIN Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (CompanyName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Company Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Description.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Description about" +
                            "your Company ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                        Company.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Contact.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        position = 1;
                        stepView.done(false);
                        stepView.go(position,true);
                        navigationButton.setText("Next");
                }

                if (CompanyContactNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Contact " +
                            "Number of Company", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (CompanyEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Company Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Pincode.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Pincode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Country.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (State.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the State", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (City.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the City", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Address1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Address 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Address2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Address 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Company.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Address.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Contact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    position = 2;
                    stepView.done(false);
                    stepView.go(position,true);
                    navigationButton.setText("Submit");
                }

                if (Name.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Email.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Mobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (Password.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Please Specify the Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {


                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("compId",0);
                        jsonObject.put("companyName",SelectedCompanyName);
                        jsonObject.put("compPrefix",null);
                        jsonObject.put("compPrefixPanAa",null);
                        jsonObject.put("companyType",3);
                        jsonObject.put("buisnessTypeId",businessTypeID);
                        jsonObject.put("description",SelectedDescription);
                        jsonObject.put("gstin",SelectedGSTIN);
                        jsonObject.put("aadharNumber",SelectedAdhaarNumber);
                        jsonObject.put("panNumber",SelectedPANNumebr);
                        jsonObject.put("associateCompanyId",41);
                        jsonObject.put("zoneId",0);
                        jsonObject.put("companyEmail",SelectedCompanyEmail);
                        jsonObject.put("companyContact",SelectedCompanyNumber);
                        jsonObject.put("companyLogo",null);
                        jsonObject.put("addressLine1",SelectedAddress1);
                        jsonObject.put("addressLine2",SelectedAddress2);
                        jsonObject.put("country",1);
                        jsonObject.put("city",160152);
                        jsonObject.put("state",56);
                        jsonObject.put("pinCode","121004");
                        jsonObject.put("contactPersonName",SelectedName);
                        jsonObject.put("contactEmail",SelectedEmail);
                        jsonObject.put("contactMobile",Integer.valueOf(SelectedMobileNumber));
                        jsonObject.put("userPassword",SelectedPassword);
                        jsonObject.put("tcsApplicable",false);
                        jsonObject.put("createByCompId",41);
                        jsonObject.put("isActive",true);
                        jsonObject.put("lastUpdatedBy",1);
                        Log.e("requestBody", jsonObject.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    SubmitRegistration(jsonObject);


                }

            }
        });

        //Get BusinessType Data
        GetBusinessTypeData getBusinessTypeData = new GetBusinessTypeData();
        getBusinessTypeData.execute();


    }

    private void SubmitRegistration(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Retrofit retrofit = BaseURL.getRetrofit();
        API apiServices = retrofit.create(API.class);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), (jsonObject).toString());
        Call<JsonObject> call = apiServices.NewRegistration(requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    String responseCode = jsonObject.getString("responseCode");
                    String responseMessage = jsonObject.getString("responseMessage");
                    Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("response", e.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

It just backs off to the previous screen.

I've tried to print error in `logcat` but it doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Other than logging, your application makes no attempt to handle the response.

Comment: If you want to know what your code is doing, learn how to use the debugger that comes with your IDE.

Comment: @Jorn yes it does not do anything except logging i don't get it how is it not handling response ? I'm beginner in android please let me know